# how do I make a model field's value be assigned to a variable and it should belong to the person logged in

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am building a services app using django and I am using stripe. The problem is that the logged in user is given a price quote and so he or she has the option to click on the price quote which will lead  them  to the test stripe payments page. everything works such  as making the charge and etc but how  do i get that specific number (price quote) which the user clicked on? that is an integer model field but I want it to be assigned to the stripe charge amount when a user clicks on it.[image]

the green button is clicked but I want that integer (quote price) of the user making the request (user is a foreign key in the quotes model) to be assigned to the stripe charge amount

how would that happen?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a view that handles the stripe request. The quote price needs to be accessible within that view.

You can create a form for each price quote and submit it if the user clicks the price quote. For example:

price_quote.html

```
<form action="{% url 'pay_using_stripe' %}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="price_quote" value="{{ price_quote }}"/>        
    <input type="submit" value="{{ price_quote }}"/>
</form>
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
   path('pay-using-stripe/', PayUsingStripe.as_view(), name='pay_using_stripe')
]
```

views.py

```
class PayUsingStripe(View):
    def post(self, request):
        price = self.request.POST.get('price_quote')
        """
          do the stripe request
        """
```

You could also use javascript and AJAX to submit a POST request to the url with the view that handles the stripe request with the price_quote as the body of the request

Comment: thanks for the help but one more thing you should know is that the estimated price quote is sent by admin...so is there a dynamic way to do this?

Comment: @violette what do you mean with 'send by admin'? please add the code how the price is rendered in the html

Comment: once a user submits a quote the admin then adds a price from the django admin and  then that shows up in the user side...like shown in picture

Comment: the price is predefined but now I want so that the user when he clicks on the price (which is the link) that very price for that logged in user can be  assigned to stripe amount argument

Comment: @violette it's hard to come up with a solution if the code is not provided but as the price_quote is shown there, my example should still work.

Comment: could you just tell me how can access that piece of data for the logged in user? piece of data which is the estimated_cost model field which has a foreign key field which  links to django User model

Comment: @violette add the code that handles the stripe request

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217222/discussion-between-vincent-and-violette).